# Prototype (1.6.0.3) function .insert does not work within dom:loaded event in Magento 1.4

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I have a strange problem regarding prototype's insert function during a dom:loaded event. Every time i use [element].insert() script execution stops for the event. I use the following code:

`document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('.some-class').insert({top: new Element('div').addClassName('top')}).insert({bottom: new Element('div').addClassName('bottom')});`

```
alert('This message never shows...');
```

});

However, if I simply change insert to invoke('hide'), all is well:

`document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('.some-class').invoke('hide');`

```
alert('This message shows...');
```

});

Does anybody know how I can get .insert working? I simply can't find a way to do this. Perhaps this has something to do with Magento as well?

Answer (score 0):

Duh!

It's so simple if you know what you are doing!

The code should be changed to the following:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('.some-class').each(function(e) {
        e.insert({top: new Element('div').addClassName('top')}).insert({bottom: new Element('div').addClassName('bottom')});
    });
});
```

That actually makes sense. I'm happy now :)